# How would I make an IntRect change once it has been defined?

Tags: c++, animation, sprite, sfml

I have a spritesheet in SFML, and I'm trying make an animated sprite myself. My idea for it is to just change the boundaries that are done with IntRect, whenever a keyboard key is pressed, but what I can't find is how to make my IntRect variable change its definitions without screwing everything up. I'd appreciate an understandable answer, as you can tell I'm a beginner at this.

A clarification of what I want to do is change `sf::IntRect characterRect(0,0,192,192)` to  `(0,192,192,192)`.

Comment: `characterRect = sf::IntRect(0,192,192,192);`; get a book.

Comment: @LogicStuff Crap, I just realized this was a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SFML's Graphics library, then you should probably be creating a subclass of `sf::Sprite`. Changing the rectangle used by a `sf::Sprite` is simple:

```
mySpriteInstance.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 192, 192, 192));
```

Remember that `sf::Rect<T>` (and its aliases, e.g. `sf::IntRect`) are - intentionally - *very inexpensive to create*. Instead of altering the properties of one you already have, just discard it and create a new one. Only bother altering/maintaining the same rectangle if it's unequivocally required.

A tutorial on the sf::Sprite class is available [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-sprite.php).